# How to query posts by ACF field but then also order by a separate ACF field?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using WP_Query to get posts that have a specific value in one of the ACF fields. I also need to order them by a separate ACF field. I am not sure how to accomplish this. Everything I've read says to use `'orderby' => 'meta_value'` but I believe thats the value of the field I'm filtering the posts by, which is not what I want.

This is what I have right now..

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'contacts',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'department',
    'meta_value' => 'Transportation',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value'
); 
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I need to `orderby` an ACF field named `last_name`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to assign a name to a meta query, and then refer to that name in your orderby. Something like this.

```
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => 'contacts',
    'post_status'            => 'publish',
    'nopaging'               => true,
    'posts_per_page'         => -1,
    'meta_query' => array( 'main_query' => array(
            'key' => 'department',
            'value' => 'Transportation'
        ), 'orderby_query' => array(
            'key' => 'last_name',
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => array(
        'orderby_query' => 'ASC',
    ),
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Ooooo nice! Didn't know that the meta queries could be used that way. Thanks!